# Autofac runtime parameters

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ioc-container, autofac

I'm new to autofac and looking to see the best practices on passing runtime values to constructor.  I've read a bunch of stackoverflow questions where this is asked but none are fully fleshed out.  Should we be using delegates, factory to create service etc.  I know passing the container around is not the best way to accomplish this.

In my particular case I have a service that access multiple dependencies, say logging, dataprovider, etc.  Along with the few services being passed I also have run-time parameters I need to capture, say userid, password.  The userid and password are required for the SomeService and are looked up when a web viewer performs a particular action. Below is what I have and highlighted is the issue.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    private readonly IDataProvider _dataProvider;
    private readonly ILog _log;
    private readonly string _username;  
    private readonly string _password;

    public SomeService(IDataProvider dataProvider, ILog log,
        string username, string password)
    {
      _dataProvider = dataProvider;
      _log = log;
      _username = username;
      _password = password;
    }
}
```

The dataprovider, and log are configured in autofac

```
builder.RegisterType<DataProviderService>().As<IDataProvider>()
builder.RegisterType<SomeLogService>().As<ILog>()
```

Most of the functionality of this "SomeService" requires a username and password to verify before performing tasks, so figured it best to pass into constructor when creating but have never dealt with run-time requirements for autofac.  I've reviewed the question [Autofac - resolving runtime parameters without having to pass container around](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22259722/autofac-resolving-runtime-parameters-without-having-to-pass-container-around) and it seems close to what I need but need some more feedback on the best way to accomplish this.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what `SomeService` is and how it uses the username and password information? That allows anyone to give you some advice that is more specific to your case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general you should [prevent passing runtime values into constructors](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99). That will complicate your design and your DI configuration a lot. Constructors are for dependencies and configuration values. Pass runtime values either through method arguments or inject a service that allows you to retrieve those runtime values. Take for instance an `IUserContext` service that allows retrieving the name current logged in user.

Comment: Aren't "configuration values" typically "runtime values?"

Comment: Nope. These are constant; they don't change during the course of the application.

Comment: Just one geek's view, but I don't feel this approach leads to good class design. Feels to me like a class implementation shouldn't even be aware of the fact that DI / IoC is occurring. If the class needs a value at construction time, I'd make it a parameter; I'd feel this way whatever Autofac's opinion/capability but it so happens they [seem to agree](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#supported-relationship-types), and as [another answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25262000/58063) mentions, Autofac does support this through parameterized instantiation.

Answer (score 8):

AutoFac supports the resolution of services with runtime parameters through the concept of [Parameterized Instantiation](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resolve/relationships.html#parameterized-instantiation-func-x-y-b).

In the constructor of the client with the dependency on the service with specific runtime parameters, declare your dependency as a `Func` which returns that dependency in terms of its **strongly typed parameters**.

E.g. `Func<string, ISomeService> myService`

When AutoFac sees the `Func` it creates a delegate that acts as a factory method for the creation of the service.

From the documentation:

> If type T is registered with the container, Autofac will automatically
>   resolve dependencies on Func as factories that create T instances
>   through the container.

It is not possible to have duplicate types in the parameter list of your dependency, as is the case of `ISomeService` in your question. E.g. `Func<string, string, ISomeService>` will not work. In this case, you need to supply a [custom delegate factory](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/advanced/delegate-factories.html).

From the documentation:

> Factory adapters provide the instantiation features of the container
>   to managed components without exposing the container itself to them.

One way to implement this approach is to declare a delegate type alongside the definition of your type that AutoFac will use as a factory method.

E.g.

```
public class SomeService : ISomeService
{
    // Factory method
    public delegate SomeService Factory(string userName, string password);

    public SomeService(IDataProvider dataProvider,
        ILog log,
        string username,
        string password)
    {
        // ..
```

Your client of ISomeService would then look like this:

```
public class MyClient
{
    public MyClient(SomeService.Factory serviceFactory)
    {
        // Resolve ISomeService using factory method
        // passing runtime parameters
        _myService = serviceFactory("this", "that");
    }
}
```

Note that all non-runtime parameters to the service (in your case IDataProvider and ILog) continue to be automatically resolved by the container.