# How to inject dependency with parameter in Orchard CMS

Tags: dependency-injection, orchardcms

I have a communication service with ip address as constructor parameter to indicate where to connect.

I want to know if I can inject this service to my controller with different ip address at run time.

All of injected service I used has a parameterless constructor at least. I know autofac can resolve type using TypedParameter or NamedParameter to pass run time parameter to constructor. But I can't inject autofac container(IContainer) to my orchardcms service or controller.

Comment: I don't think this is going to work. Why do you need the IP address in the constructor?

Comment: The ip can be customized by user. The it will changed at runtime. So I can't init the communication service when the application starts up

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection is about injecting behavior, not data. This is a job for configuration. You should look at any example of an existing Orchard feature that uses configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need is parameterized instantiation.

Please read the answers to the following question: [Autofac runtime parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25253381/autofac-runtime-paramet%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bers)